# How to scrape a website where details are not on the inspect page?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this website that I need to scrape.

https://www.dawn.com

My goal is to scrape all news content with the keyword "Pakistan"

So far, I can only scrape the content if I have the URL. For example:

```
from newspaper import Article
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

url = 'https://www.dawn.com/news/1582311/who-chief-lauds-pakistan-for-suppressing-covid-19-while-keeping-economy-afloat'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
article.summary
```

From this code, I wrote I would to copy and paste all the URLs and that is too much to do manually. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: One way to do this is to use the [search url](https://www.dawn.com/search?cx=partner-pub-8258178831251847%3A5337004877&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Pakistan%22) and then fetch all the links on the page. Once you have accomplished that you can create another code loop to scrape all the urls from the originally scrapped URLs.

Comment: Yep! I fetched the links via javascript and went from there.

Answer (score 0):

better is goto> https://www.dawn.com/pakistan & download (.html) then scrape all the news content, later bifurcate using keywords.